# Accessing 3 characters from a string every time in C

Tags: c, string, file

I'm trying to get data from a file. The file has integer data in every line. The length of data varies every line. While I'm accessing each line with `fgets()`, I'm getting the line in a string format. I want to access 3 characters of the string every time till newline (`\n`) appears.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{ 
    int k,a;
    char res[300] = "";
    char buff[1026];
    FILE *ip,*op;
    ip = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    op= fopen(argv[2],"w+");
    if( ip == NULL) 
           {
                     perror("An error has occurred\n");
                       exit(1);
           }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
    {       i=0;
            int len = sizeof(buff) / sizeof(buff[0]);
```

Now buff has the first line of the file as a string. I want to use a for loop to get 3 characters of the string each time until `\n`, then my program will move to next line.

I'm more of a Python guy and in Python I can do it by using a for loop and accessing the index `[i:i+2]`. That will give me 3 indices every time, not sure how to do it in C. Maybe I can take another string (`S1`) and iterate over `buff` for 3 characters every time and append the 3 characters in the new string. Then I'll do my validations and initialize the string `S1` for next iteration. It seems kind of messy.

Is there any other good way to do it? Please help.

Comment: Please complete the example code (it is not copied nor formatted correctly).

Comment: I'm trying to use the buff[4] in a switch quantity. But I'm getting an error because it's not an integer. Any advice for that?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm more of a python guy and in python I can do it by using a for loop and accessing the index [i:i+2]. That will give me 3 indices every time, not sure how to do it in C.

Given index `i`, you want to access `s[i]`, `s[i+1]` and `s[i+2]` in C.

To copy all 3 in one go, you could use `memcpy` or `strncpy` giving a starting address of `&s[i]`.

For instance, if you do not care about the null character, you may do:

```
char d[3];
memcpy(d, &s[i], 3);
```

Comment: That means I have to use a new string and copy 3 indices each time to the new string from buff. Am I correct?

Comment: @Conquistador Not necessarily, you can also access the characters directly as I wrote in the first line. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Conquistador these things aren't 'indices'. They're characters.

Comment: @Acorn, d will be a pointer , right? Can I do something so that I'll get that as a string so that I need to do some validation going forward in my program? Sorry for the question, but really confused in pointer concepts. Newbie to C.

Comment: `d` is an array, but yes, when you pass it to `memcpy` it will behave like a pointer to the first element. (`&d[0]`). I am not sure what you mean "*that as a string*". Perhaps ask a new question!

Comment: I'm trying to do the following: if(d>900){strcat(res,"A")}. res is a empty string defined earlier. When I'm trying to print d, (with %s), it's giving me desired output. But while I'm trying to use d in an if-else statement, it's not going inside the conditional statement.

Comment: @Conquistador `d>900` does not make sense. What are you trying to do? (Please post the exact code in a new question!)